# Can't access to Outlook or OneDrive online on Office365 on Firefox

Tags: firefox, 19.04, 19.10, office365

While I can access to Office/Office365 domains (office.com), once I'm there I can open Word, Excel… online, but Outlook and OneDrive never load and they keep going back to the login screen.

On the status bar is a `sending request for mydomain-my.sharepoint.com/...` and `waiting for login.microsoftonline.com…` dancing all the time until it go back tot the login account.

It's not a network problem, because Chromium Browser can totally login on and load those services in the same computer without a problem, while Firefox can't.

This problem happened to me before. Last week I installed ubuntu 18 LTS and there Firefox was behaving like this, while Chromium wasn't. I update to Ubuntu 19.04 and the problem just went away. Now I installed Ubuntu 19.10 as a fresh install and the problem is back.

Either, I installed something that fixed the problem or the update to 19.04 did it for me, but I really don't know what it could be.

Any ideas what is going on?

Using Chromium isn't that big deal, but I really prefer to use Firefox.

PS1/ I've already tried to delete my firefox profile and delete the cookies and so on and so forth, with no avail.

PS2/ As you all can see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1182570/753797), the problem fixed by itself… but I really love to get some real answers and know what was going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough the problem fixed again by itself after a while. I just installed Microsoft Teams for Linux form the Snap shop and now works.

PS/ Anyhow, I would love to know what was going on, so I really appreciate if anyone can answer.